# How to implement partial-query caching with apollo-server (gRPC, not REST)

Tags: apollo-server

I've tried setting up full GraphQL query response cache with apollo-server v2, only to find that it does not do a good enough job of reducing network requests.

What I need i think is called partial-query cache.

Consider this schema:

```
type Post @cacheControl(maxAge: 240) {
  id: Int!
  title: String
  comments: [Comment]
}

type Comment @cacheControl(maxAge: 50) {
  id: Int!
  title: String
  text: String
}
```

When querying `{ post(id: "1") { id, title, comments } }` I do not want to refetch post if less than 240 seconds have passed. With the full GraphQL query response the whole query will refetch based on the lowest maxAge.

This is where I hope partial-query cache will come to the rescue.

Unfortunately it states here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/resources/faq/#what-kinds-of-cache-should-i-set-up that partial-query cache can only be implemented with redis/memcached and only if using datasources.

Since my services are gRPC services and not REST, I cannot use datasources - and ideally I'd prefer if it was possible without datasources.

So if possible, how can I implement partial-query cache with Apollo Server v2, without datasources. And if that is not possible, how can I implement a gRPC datasource with partial query cache?

Would it be possible to somehow modify this: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/master/packages/apollo-server-plugin-response-cache/src/ApolloServerPluginResponseCache.ts so you can still control it with @cacheControl but for partial-query caching instead of caching full queries?